# Move values from a column to another column in different table mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `jos_users` with blank column `usertype`
and
I have a table named `jos_users_old` with column with values `usertype`

What I want is to move all values from column `usertype` of `jos_users_old` table tp the blank column `usertype` of `jos_users`

I tried

```
UPDATE jos_users AS t1 
INNER JOIN jos_users_old AS t2 
ON t1.usertype = t2.usertype 
SET t1.usertype = t2.usertype;
```

It came back with "0 rows are affected"

Can you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Query looks good, perhaps there is no matching data ?

Comment: You can't join the tables on `usertype` columns, because these don't match in those two tables. Otherwise there will be no need to update it in table `t1`. Do you have any other field to join on?

Comment: This QUERY WORKED FOR ME: UPDATE jos_users g JOIN jos_users_old b    
ON g.id = b.id
SET g.usertype = b.usertype_old ; after I changed the column in the old table from usertype to usertype_old

Comment: @Jenny It's strange you had to rename the column to `usertype_old`. With the corrected join (`g.id = b.id`), it should work with `g.usertype = b.usertype` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should used the key of the table to do the join ON the two table 
Because if t1.usertype is always blank you will never have t1.usertype = any t2.usertype

You should use t1.id = t2.id

You can also do a NATURAL JOIN an then make the link with a WHERE